# Displaying single product through list.phtml edit

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

So what i'm trying to achieve is that the product with the attribute 'promotion' set to 'yes' is displayed on the frontpage of the website. This is working, but the .phtml file i'am using with this is the regular list.phtml. This is currently showing all the items I have set to promotion but I only want to show 1.

So in short: How do I edit the list.phtml to only show 1 product instead of everything?

Answer (score 1):

Change how you are pulling your collection. Clone/Rename your list.phtml, for example promotion.phtml. Then change this line, from this:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

To this:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addFieldToFilter('promotion', 1)
                        ->addAttributeToSort('updated_at', 'DESC')
                        ->clear()->setPageSize(1)->load();
```

And it should load only one item with promotion set to yes. Make sure you set the new template in either your CMS Page Content or XML, depending on which method this is added.

**Explanation**

- `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()`: Gets the Product Collection. You can get other collections by changing the model, such as "catalog/category" and "cms/page".
- `->addAttributeToSelect('*')`: Adds All Product Columns. This can be exchanged for things like `('name', 'url')`. I'm assuming it's faster than loading all but I haven't benchmarked it. Since you're using the full template it's probably best to leave this set to all.
- `->addFieldToFilter('promotion', 1)`: Filters out products by attributes. Here we have the products filtered for all those with the 'promotion' attribute set to 1(yes/true). Products use this one, while categories use `->addAttributeToFilter()` oddly enough. Definitely give Alan Storm's Collection Explanation(link below) a read through to know what all you can do with this one. You can add multiple filters to your collection, either by adding another `->addFieldToFilter()`, or storing your filters in nested arrays.
- `->addAttributeToSort('updated_at', 'DESC')`: Sorts the product collection by specific attribute and direction. Here I have the "updated_at" date set to descending order, "ASC" is ascending. You can add multiple sorting attributes, pay attention to the order you add them in, of course.
- `->clear()->setPageSize(1)->load()`: These three are needed to make adjustments to how much the collection pulls. `->clear()` must be called before it will allow changing how many products are pulled. The `->setPageSize()` bit is where you specify how many products you would like to return, and `->load()` of course loads the collection. Note that if you do not limit the size of the collection returned, you do not need this entire line, the products will iterate without having to call `->load()`.

**Resources**

Alan Storm said it best, give this a read and you should be a pro at manipulating collections: http://alanstorm.com/magento_collections